# Pull a file from a Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

I can see that it's possible to insert a file into a Docker container via `insert`:

```
docker insert IMAGE URL PATH
```

Is there a way to fetch the contents of a file in a Docker container and save them somewhere on the host operating system? I'd like to extract the value of a configuration file and store it on my host operating system.

Comment: Two things:
 1. docker insert worked on IMAGE files, not containers.
 2. it was deprecated in 0.10.0 and no longer exists.

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331645/extract-file-from-docker-image

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Depends on which version of the docker tool you're using:

- The current version has an ordinary 'cp' command, according to [cp doc v0.6.3](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

  > Usage: docker cp CONTAINER:PATH HOSTPATH
  > Copy files/folders from the containers filesystem to the host
  > path.  Paths are relative to the root of the filesystem.
- For older version, you may consider to use 'export' as from [export doc v0.5.3](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/):

  > Usage: docker export CONTAINER
  > Export the contents of a filesystem as a tar archive

(There may also be other options, based on capabilities of your container.)