# Extract file from docker image?

Tags: docker

I'd like to extract a file from a Docker image without having to run the image.

The `docker save` option is not currrently a viable option for me as it's saving too huge of a file just to un-tar a specific file.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can extract files from an image with the following commands:

```bsh
container_id=$(docker create "$image")
docker cp "$container_id:$source_path" "$destination_path"
docker rm "$container_id"
```

According to the `docker create` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#extended-description), this doesn't run the container:

> The `docker create` command creates a writeable container layer over the specified image and prepares it for running the specified command. The container ID is then printed to `STDOUT`. This is similar to `docker run -d` except the container is never started. You can then use the `docker start <container_id>` command to start the container at any point.

---

For reference (my previous answer), a less efficient way of extracting a file from an image is the following:

```bsh
docker run some_image cat "$file_path" > "$output_path"
```

Comment: You might want to over-ride the entrypoint. `docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh my_image -c /bin/cat some_file`

Comment: This runs the image, which is specifically what I didn't want to do as stated in my question.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point.  I agree my current answer isn't satisfactory then.

Comment: I was just thinking you might do something like: `docker create image`, `docker cp container:/file_path /output_path` but that doesn't seem to actually work unless you also do `docker start container` before the `cp`, which likely runs the container.

Comment: Never mind what I said about `docker start`, it's probably not needed.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @BlakBat Does this updated answer work for you? I guess I should have created a new answer but it's done now.

Comment: @bbc This updated answer does in fact not start a container (the crux of the question), and does not require to be root.

Comment: Used your answer to extract `jvm.options` from the elasticsearch-docker. This small script will get the latest version: `CONTAINER_ID=$(docker create $(docker image ls | awk '$1 ~ /\/elasticsearch-docker/ { print $2, $3 }' | sort -V | tail -1 | awk '{ print $2 }')) ; docker cp ${CONTAINER_ID}:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options /tmp/jvm.options ; docker rm ${CONTAINER_ID}`.

Comment: I would like to add, if you built an image that does not have a runnable command, when running the docker create command you may get the error `Error response from daemon: No command specified`
In this case, add a dummy command after the image name. It can be `dummycommand` or any made up gibberish, since it won't actually be run.

Answer (score 9):

None of the above worked for me. The complete working command is:

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh image_name -c "cat /path/filename" > output_filename
```

Without quotes `cat` is passed without filename, so it does not know what to show. Also it is a good idea to delete the container after command is finished.

Comment: The command you're referring to will only work depending on the docker and how correctly ENTRYPOINT / CMD was set in the Dockerfile; this has nothing to do with quoting. You also say to delete the container, yet you specify --rm. Lastly, when I had posted my question I specified "without having to run the image" and no answers were a solution taking this into account.

Comment: Regardless which CMD and ENTRYPOINT were set in Dockerfile I override both, so it would work always (on Linux of course). What do you mean by "depending on the docker"? Settings, version, env, what? You question is not correct because images cannot be executed, only containers can. I think there is no correct answer, you have to deal with many files or create a temporary container. --rm removes the temporary container, other's answers leave some junk on your disk.

Comment: Can simplify quoting by skipping the shell: `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/cat image_name /path/filename > output_filename`

Comment: This answer works, but unfortunately, I came here after figuring out another way, might help someone it's a bit shorter too...
`docker run --entrypoint /bin/cat image_name /path/filename > filename`

Comment: @lauksas Yes, it shorter, but a little harder to read, because `cat` and `/path/filename` are in different places, but they work together. Also without `--rm` you leave some junk on disk until you prune docker explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

If storing the full output of `docker save` isn't an option, you could use pipelines to extract just the needed file from it.

Unfortunately, because the output is a "tar of tars", it can be a slightly iterative process.

What I did when I needed to extract a file just now was:

1. Determine which version of the image the file you are interested in changed most recently (how you do this probably depends on your image), and the date it was created / saved
2. Get the full table of contents from the output of the `docker save` command with:

   docker save IMAGE_NAME | tar -tvf -
3. Find the `layer.tar` file(s) in the output of that command that match the date of the image that you determined in step 1. (you can add `| grep layer.tar` to just show those files)
4. Extract that `layer.tar` file to standard out, and get the table of contents of it:

   docker save IMAGE_NAME | tar -xf - -O CHECKSUM_FROM_LIST/layer.tar | tar -tvf -
5. Verify the file you want is listed, and extract it once you find the name:

   docker save IMAGE_NAME | tar -xf - -O CHECKSUM_FROM_LIST/layer.tar | tar -xf - PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE

If there are more than one `layer.tar` files matching the date you are looking for in step 2/3, you may need to repeat step 4 for each one of them until you find the right one

Replace the text in capitals in the commands above with the correct image names, checksums and filenames for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Docker containers
store cached files created in the following directory for Ubuntu:

`/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<container_id>`

From there you should be able to access the file system and retrieve your file(s).

Comment: Nope. That directory only contains `layersize` and `json`, and is also not user readable (even if user is in docker group). `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` will contain the file that I look for (but is categorized not by container id) and is also not readable.

Comment: Give me a few and I will look it up. I know for a fact there is a way to retreive the files without entering the container or running it.

Comment: By not readable, how does it show? I have found an example where you can pull text files from the containers by going to the /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/* directory

Comment: My mistake. User can access `/var/lib/docker/aufs` (but not all other directories in `/var/lib/docker/`)

Comment: Can you access as root?

Comment: This approach highly depends on which storage driver (aka "graph driver") your docker is using (run `docker info` to check).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option which does not even create the container and avoids fiddling with the layers manually, but may act funny if multiple layers contain some of the files you're interested in:

```
$ docker image save IMAGE_NAME | tar --extract --wildcards --to-stdout '*/layer.tar' | tar --extract --ignore-zeros --verbose FILE_OR_DIRECTORY
```